# Using hyphen in link_to property?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, html, anchor

In my Rails app, I need to set a value for a custom [data-*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data) attribute on an anchor tag.  However, hashes can't have hyphens if I'm not mistaken.  I essentially want to do this:

```
<%= link_to 'Example', example_path, :class => 'something', :data-id => '15' %>
```

`:data-id` is not valid, however.  What can I do to work around this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IIRC, for such purposes hashes and strings are equivalent, so you can use "data-id" instead of :data-id. Never checked for this particular method, though, so no guarantees.

Comment: Also `:"data-id"` is a valid symbol, but it looks ugly and I would never do that personally..

Answer (score 7):

I think in Rails 3 you can do

`link_to "Click Here", root_path, :data => { :id => @model.id }`

for all data attributes.